# How can i keep my rabbitmq channel open for long running jobs?

Tags: rabbitmq, timeout, channel, consumer

I am using rabbitmq version 3.9.27. Here I am facing issues with long running jobs, as consumer timeout is set to 30 minutes. So for jobs taking longer than 30 minutes, the channel is getting closed and job is getting requeued.

Error:
`channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 4 timed out. Timeout value used: 3600000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more, class-id=0, method-id=0)`

Is there a way to keep rabbit channel alive while long running jobs are getting processed?

- I am bound not to increase the consumer_timeout limit to more than 1 hour, and jobs can take upto 2 hours of time.